# Windows 7: Custom width of a specific taskbar icon,

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, fixed-width

I'm using [Taskbar Meters](https://taskbarmeters.codeplex.com/) as a convenient way to keep my resource usage visible at all times. If you are not familiar with the product, it opens separate windows for memory, CPU, and disk usage with the taskbar button behaving as a bar graph. This looks great when the taskbar is set to "always combine, hide labels" but when labels are shown the meters are taking up valuable real estate. Is there a way to hide the labels or to force these icons to a fixed width while kepping the other open programs with full size labeled icons?

Comment: Also see: [How do I customize the width of the icons in the Windows 7 taskbar?](http://superuser.com/questions/25349/how-do-i-customize-the-width-of-the-icons-in-the-windows-7-taskbar?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you, I has tried looking but couldn't find it. Does this question get removed?